# ZSH alias that changes "cd folder/ls" to "cd folder/ && ls"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, zsh, oh-my-zsh, zshrc

I usually mistype and write

```
➜~ cd folder/ls
```

instead of

```
➜~ cd folder/
➜~ ls
```

(I type "ls" before pressing enter).

Do you know any possible aliases that can help me with that? Or any other solutions.

I've already tried `alias /ls=" && ls"` but of course, it didn't help :( The alias is triggered only when I purely write "/ls".

Comment: I don't think that's possible since folder/ls can't be distinguished from any other string input you might want to pass to your alias command, so I don't think this is possible to create

Comment: Note that on Unix, BSD--and Linux, too--they are "directories" and not the Windows concept of "folders" which is not the same thing though I do see Ubuntu and other user OSes doing that.

Comment: @stamaks : What would your desired alias do if there **were** a folder `folder/ls`? If your alias would work,it would be inconvenient to cd into this folder. Instead of trying some semi-intelligent "do-what-I-mean" setup, you are better off practicing your typing. This is a skill you can use also in other context (writing documents or programs), not only in the shell. What zsh **can** do for you is to let you get rid of typing the word `cd` itself. You still would have to hit the return key, though.